AJAX-based Website Always Returns to Homepage on Refresh – How to Fix?
I have developed a website using AJAX for navigation between pages. While navigation works fine during the session, every time I refresh the page, it automatically redirects to the homepage instead of staying on the current page. The URL in the address bar does not change as I navigate, which I suspect is part of the problem. I am looking for a way to maintain the current page state even after a refresh.
Here are the key points about the site's behavior:

The site uses AJAX to load content without reloading the page.
The URL in the address bar remains the same regardless of the content displayed.
Refreshing the page always leads back to the homepage.
The backend is written in C#
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to modify my AJAX calls or configure my server to handle page refreshes correctly and maintain the state or page position after a refresh.

Thank you in advance for your help!
I tried to handle this problem with a script in javascript that saves the pageId and when load the homepage as it usually does, it checks this pageId and redirects to it.   it didn't worked fine and it doesn't seem the best solution. I tried already to change to routing configuration in C# config file but it always load the homepage after refresh.

it is a good solution. but you want to set the URL for this exact purpose. you can use window.hash then when loading the page, check the window.hash and load the right content
